# Unhighlighted text is still copied to the clipboard in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

There were some discussion in the past about *disabling highlighting* some parts of the *selected text* in Web pages, so the user is not able to *visually* select them (e. g. [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/7023590)).

But they are still selected when the user selects it (e. g. with the adjacent text without the anti-highlighting protection).

So he or she press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to be surprised - the text in the *clipboard* is different from the *selected one*.

Is there some way to *exclude a non-highlighted text from the selecting it, too*?

---

**Edited:**

This problem manifests itself only in Chrome browser, other browsers don't select non-highlighted text (thanks to [evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/989920/evolutionxbox)) so my question is now:

*How reach my goal for Chrome, too?*

Comment: Are you using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css#answer-4407335 solution?

Comment: @Morpheus OP's issue is still prevalent even when using `user-select`.

Comment: the most upvoted answer on the question you linked seems to do exactly what you're after ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css

Comment: @andrew you can still copy and select text if the adjacent text is not "protected".

Comment: @evolutionxbox probably depends on the browser. The most upvoted answer works fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: @Morpheus what browser are you using? http://jsbin.com/neqetuvori/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @evolutionxbox yup, now I can see the problem.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - It works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) it still selects (and copies) "protected" text, too.

Comment: @MarianD I know. That's my jsbin link shows.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - Oh, I mistakenly reacted to Morpheus 1st comment ("works fine for me on Chrome"). In spite of it your link was valuable for me as I found out that in Firefox it works fine. (Previously I worked only with Chrome and I didn't tested my code in other browsers as I naively supposed that Chrome is good enough.)